# How to create github release using TravisCI from multiple build matrixes?

Tags: go, travis-ci

I have setup a simple go repository and configured TravisCI in the following way

```
language: go

go:
  - 1.8.x
  - master

gobuild_args: -ldflags "-X main.Version=${TRAVIS_TAG} -X main.buildTime=`date -u '+%Y-%m-%d_%I:%M:%S%p'` -X main.commitId=${TRAVIS_COMMIT}"

env:
  - GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64
  - GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64

after_success:
  - ./build.sh

matrix:
  allow_failures:
  - go: master
```

This will essentially create 4 different builds in TravisCI. This is great for building a cross compilation project where I can build windows and linux binaries separately.

What I have been struggling to do is to create 1 single release in Github from all the binaries generated across those builds?

TravisCI documentation says they support releases but it is very vague on how to handle such a scenario.

- Don't all the the build run on different virtual servers? If so how do I specify the file in each
- If I setup a release will it run for each build? How does work with github, will it fail because the release will be attempted to be created several times?

Has anybody attempted this?

Comment: For cross platform compilation in Go, check out [gox](https://github.com/mitchellh/gox).  It's makes building for all possible platforms a breeze!

Comment: Thank you but I am avoiding gox on purpose as I want to keep to the standard tooling as much as I can. Besides I am not having problems building, it is the publishing that is the issue

Comment: is this of interest https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/929 ? Maybe you can use script deploy and do some bash trick to skip or upload https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/script/.